# Angular 2 not updating the DOM after changes on model

Tags: dom, angular, updates

I am having some trouble on angular2 that I can't manage to understand. The problem is that View won't update after an HTTP request is done correctly.

I am reassigning the variable (not updating the object in the reference), and I am also testing some extra divs with *ngIf property based on a boolean. Dom will not update, neither divs and neither {{ object interpolation }}

This is the view:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">Loading data...</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">{{ perfil | json }}</div>

Debug: {{ perfil | json }}

<a (click)="test()" >Click test</a>
```

And this is the component code:

```
export class GitTestComponent implements OnInit{

    perfil: GithubProfile = <GithubProfile>{}; //Also tested just "perfil: GithubProfile;"
    isLoading: boolean = true;

    constructor(private _githubService: GithubService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this._githubService.getProfile('jaimehrubiks')
            .timeout(5000)
            .subscribe(
                (profile) => this.perfil = profile,
                (error) => console.log(error),
                () => this.isLoading = false
            )
    }

    test(){

    }

}
```

As a note, DOM will in fact update if I click on the anchor or any element with an event assigned to it.

Here is the service code in case the problem is there:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable' //Also tested rxjs/Rx
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {GithubUser, GithubProfile, GithubFollowers} from './github.interface'


@Injectable()
export class GithubService{

    usersUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/";

    constructor(private _http: Http){

    }

    getUser(user: string) : Observable<GithubUser>{
        return this._http.get(this.usersUrl + user)
                    .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getFollowers(user: string) : Observable<GithubFollowers>{
        return this._http.get(this.usersUrl + user + '/followers')
                    .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getProfile(user: string) : Observable<GithubProfile>{
         return Observable.forkJoin(
                            this.getUser(user), 
                            this.getFollowers(user))
                .map( joined => <GithubProfile> new Object( {user: joined[0], followers: joined[1]} )  )
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually happens if the change is pushed from an action that isn't in the Angular Zone.  I am not sure what in the code you provided would trigger out of zone model update, but it probably is the same thing.  See [this related question and fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354707/how-to-make-injected-service-reactive-in-angular2-meteor/39358081)

Comment: Ok, fine, thank you. I fixed it:
`this._zone.run( () => {
                        this.isLoading = false
                    });
`
However I don't understand why did it run out of the zone in the first place.
I'd like to know how to prevent the service to run out of the ng zone.